# Virtual Machine on IOS?

Tags: ios

Are there any virtual machine emulators for the Ios? When I mean virtual machine emulator for the Ios, I mean virtual machine software that can be used on an Ios to emulate something like a mac or linux. (like a port of qemu) Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Not without jailbreaking. However, you could use something like TeamViewer to control your Mac or PC. I know it's not the same, but it's as close as you'll get without jailbreaking. I hope this helps!